# making 2 columns unique despite of order MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two fields in my database set with constraint of unique key. I need to have those 2 fields unique as I'm using it to determine whether a duplicate is about to be inserted and instead just update the fields.
This is the query to insert/update them:

```
INSERT INTO quiz(player1, player2, array, email1, email2) 
VALUES (:user1, :user2, :quests, :email1, :email2) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE player1=:user1, player2=:user2, array=:quests, email1=:email1, email2=:email2"
```

The unique fields are `player1` and `player2`.

That works fine however it does count the order in which the values are inserted into the `player1` and `player2` fields. Therefore I want values inserted into player1, player2 -> e.g. `user1`, `user2` to be treated the same as `user2`, `user1`. Is it possible to set it up in a database - or do I need additional functions in PHP for update?

Comment: So you have a field called `player1` and a field called `player2` but you don't differentiate between them? All you really want is to link some data to 2 `player`s?

Comment: I do differentiate between them - the usernames have to be in separate fields - however I don't want two different rows for a pair of the same players - if the same player names are to be entered I just want to update their row - not create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across this situation many times and the short answer is that I think you'll have to add some PHP code to check if the user2, user1 record already exists before inserting the user1, user2 record.

---

Alternatively, you might consider altering the DB to something like this:

```
Matches Table
 id
 created_at
 updated_at

Participants Table
 id
 user_id
 match_id
 created_at
 updated_at

Users table
 id
 username
 email
 etc...

Quiz Table
 id
 match_id
 etc...
```

This might seem like more work at first, but it has proven to be a lot easier to work with in the long run because it will allow you to query your data a lot easier if you plan on doing more advanced queries. You could then do a unique index on the user_id and match_id. If all you need is to get it done quick and dirty, go with the way you already have it and just add some PHP validation. If you want it to be done correctly in the long run and plan on doing some more advanced queries, you should consider changing your table structure.